# I want to implement it as shown in the picture.(Draw Diagonal Line in WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml

[image]

I want to implement it like the picture above.

[image]

```
 <Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#eeeeee" Height="200" Width="300">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Background="#55a0c4">
                <TextBlock Text="묘도대교 PY1 탑정부" Padding="6" Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="White" Margin="0 0 0 0">
                <Path Stroke="#55a0c4" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0 4 0 0">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1" />
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Border>
            <Border Background="#55a0c4" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="5"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The above picture and code are embodied by me, but I cannot fill the background only in the above margin. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a different geometry. Instead of drawing a line, draw a triangle. This will fill most of the area you want. Then you just need to also include a rectangle to fill the space above the triangle. Here's a version of your code that does what you want:

```xml
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#eeeeee" Height="200" Width="300">
  <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="#55a0c4">
      <TextBlock Text="묘도대교 PY1 탑정부" Padding="6" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="White" Margin="0 0 0 0">
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Path Fill="#55a0c4" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0 5 0 0" Data="M 0,0 H 1 L 0,1 Z"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#55a0c4" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border Background="#55a0c4" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="5"/>
  </Grid>
</Border>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Please note that I also added `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` to the parent `Grid` element. This is necessary to inhibit antialiasing that would result in faint gaps between the graphical elements.

I also used the ["Path Markup Syntax"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax) to define the triangle, instead of building the `Path` object's data with explicit XAML elements. I find this much more concise, if sometimes not as readable.

Comment: Yes. It's actually pretty simple. There aren't many operations, and they are all basic vector commands. It's a little like programming a plotter. :) Of course, it helps that all I was drawing was a triangle. That's not hard to figure out. For complex data, I use InkScape, which is an open-source vector-drawing program that has a way to export WPF-compatible geometry streams (that's what the markup is called).